# Is there any way I can code to read txt file of atomic coordinates to represent each colum as a list

Tags: python, list, file

This is the atomic coordinates

```
XYZ
A 5.98974561 7.80124465 15.1032457
B 5.60245671 7.50214457 16.0012454
```

I started coding as

```
with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readlines()
        if not line:
           break
        print((line[1]))
        print((line[2]))
```

And the results came as:

```
A 5.98974561 7.80124465 15.1032457
B 5.60245671 7.50214457 16.0012454
```

But I wanted it to be

```
A = [5.98974561 7.80124465 15.1032457]
B = [5.60245671 7.50214457 16.0012454]
```

Comment: "printing" will always create a string. If you want a list, what do you plan to do with it in your code?

Comment: You cannot get a list with the name as the first column and its items as other columns. Please create a dictionary with keys as `A`, `B` and its values as coordinates. Also, you'll need to split the lines to get individual coordinates using `line.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this with [Abuday's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15833313/abhyuday-vaish) suggestion:

```py
with open(filename) as f:
   lines = f.readlines()[1:]
    
dictionary = {}    
for i in lines:
   dictionary[i.split()[0]] = i.split()[1:]
```

This will give you a dictionary with indices (A, B, ...) as keys and lists as values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could suite you

```
with open(filename) as f:
    line = f.readline() # to skip first line
    col_0 = [] # so store the first column
    col_1 = [] # so store the second column
    col_2 = [] # so store the third column
    col_3 = [] # so store the fourth column
    while True:
        line = f.readline() # read line one  by one
        if not line:
           break
        line = line.replace('\n','') # replace line return with nothing
        splitline = line.split(' ')
        col_0.append(splitline[0]) # append value of the first column + convert to float
        col_1.append(float(splitline[1])) # append value of the second column + convert to float
        col_2.append(float(splitline[2])) # append value of the third column  + convert to float
        col_3.append(float(splitline[3])) # append value of the fourth column + convert to float
        print(splitline[0] + ' = ' + str(splitline[1]) + ' ' + str(splitline[2]) + ' ' + str(splitline[3])   )
print(col_0)
print(col_1)
print(col_2)
print(col_3)
```

But I think there is more efficient ways to read 3D coordinate files. For example using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
filename = 't.txt'
Name = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1, usecols=0,dtype = 'S1' )
Coordianates = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1, usecols=(1,2,3) )
print( Name,Coordianates)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce the **exact** output as shown in the question then:

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'
with open(FILENAME) as data:
    for line in data.readlines()[1:]:
        t = line.split()
        print(f'{t[0]} = [{" ".join(t[1:])}]')
```

**Output:**

```
A = [5.98974561 7.80124465 15.1032457]
B = [5.60245671 7.50214457 16.0012454]
```